# Composing methods for Async workflow in .NET

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am having a bit of trouble in composing a async workflow.
Here's what I have.
There is a method SearchForProducts() which returns a list of products
This method calls three other methods inside it to do it's job like so:

```
public List<Products> SearchForProducts(string Phrase, int Id)
    {

    var Products = new List<Products>();
    var searchedProducts = SearchProducts(Phrase);

    var sellingPrice = GetSellingPrice(Id);
    var discounts = GetDiscounts(Id);

    Products = searchedProducts;
    Products = ProcessForSellingPrice(Products, sellingPrice);
    Products = ProcessForDiscounts(Products, discounts, Id); 

    return Products;
    }
```

All three SearchProducts, GetSellingPrice & GetDiscounts return a list of Products after executing a Stored Proc.
I tried using the async key word on one of them and awaiting the result like so:

```
public async List<Products> SearchProducts(string Phrase)
    {
        var Products = new List<Products>();

        try
        {

            Products = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<Products>("EXEC Search_Products @pharse",
                           new SqlParameter("pharse", Phrase)).ToList();,

        }

        return Products;
    }
```

This gives the following errors:

```
Cannot await 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Products>'    

The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>
```

GetSellingPrice, & GetDiscounts also have the same implementations where they call different Stored procs.

How do I go about making SearchProducts, GetSellingPrice, & GetDiscounts async so that the result after the three execute can be passed to these methods:

```
Products = searchedProducts;
Products = ProcessForSellingPrice(Products, sellingPrice);
Products = ProcessForDiscounts(Products, discounts, Id);
```

Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE]**

After searching I found this solution that worked.
I created a task for each of the three method calls like so:

```
var searchProductsTask = new Task<List<Product>>(() => SearchProducts(Phrase));
```

Created an array for all the tasks:

```
 var tasksList = new Task[] {searchProductsTask, 2ndTask, 3rdTask }
```

Started each task like so:

```
searchProductsTask.Start();
```

Waited till of them completed:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasksList);
```

Called the .Result on the specific task where the result was required

```
var searchedProducts = searchProductsTask.Result;
```

Comment: The biggest hint I think you have is that "The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>". Try thinking about it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `SearchProducts` method to call `ToListAsync()`

```
Products = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<Products>("EXEC Search_Products @pharse",
                      new SqlParameter("pharse", Phrase)).ToListAsync();
```

Once you do that to all your other methods, you should be able to just `await` the results

```
Products = await searchedProducts;
Products = ProcessForSellingPrice(Products, await sellingPrice);
Products = ProcessForDiscounts(Products, await discounts, Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but your first method is not async so it doesn't wait for the result so you have to pass void. Do for example something like this:

```
public async void SearchProducts(string Phrase, int id)
{
    var Products = new List<Products>();

    try
    {

        Products = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<Products>("EXEC Search_Products @pharse",
                       new SqlParameter("pharse", Phrase)).ToList();,
        var searchedProducts = SearchProducts(Phrase);

        var sellingPrice = GetSellingPrice(Id);
        var discounts = GetDiscounts(Id);

        Products = searchedProducts;
        Products = ProcessForSellingPrice(Products, sellingPrice);
        Products = ProcessForDiscounts(Products, discounts, Id);
        CallWhateverMethodYouWantForProduct(Products);
    }

}
```

Comment: Async void?? Not a good idea here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: I'm just responding to the given error ;) I would use BackgroundWorker tbh